# function to aggregate a set of data and output nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, defaultdict

I have looked all over for a solution to this problem and i can't find anything which works in the way that i am trying to achieve.

I want to create a Python function which has three arguments

1. data_object - this is a list of dictionaries where each dictionary has the same fields - anywhere from 1-n amount of 'dimension' fields to group by, and anywhere from 1-n amount of metrics fields to be aggregated.
2. dimensions - the list of dimension fields to group by
3. metrics - the list of metric fields to aggregate

The way i have solved this problem previously is to use setdefault:

```
struc = {}
for row in rows:
    year = row['year']
    month = row['month']
    affiliate = row['affiliate']
    website = row['website']
    pgroup = row['product_group']
    sales = row['sales']
    cost = row['cost']
    struc.setdefault(year, {})
    struc[year].setdefault(month, {})
    struc[year][month].setdefault(affiliate, {})
    struc[year][month][affiliate].setdefault(website, {})
    struc[year][month][affiliate][website].setdefault(pgroup, {'sales':0, 'cost':0})
    struc[year][month][affiliate][website][pgroup]['sales'] += sales
    struc[year][month][affiliate][website][pgroup]['cost'] += cost
```

The problem is that the fieldnames, the amount of dimension fields, and the amount of metrics fields will all be different if i'm looking at a different set of data

I have seen posts about recursive functions and defaultdict but (unless i misunderstood them) they all either require you to know how many dimension and metric fields you want to work with OR they don't output a dictionary object which is what i require.

Comment: Just out of interest @thefourtheye, why did you edit this? I am specifically trying to make function to be used in Python so is it not sensible to put that in the title of the question?

Comment: The actual language or technologies are preferred in the tags rather than in the titles. That is why I edited that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was so much simpler than i thought :)

My main problem was if you have n dimensions - how do you reference the correct level of the dictionary when you are looping through the dimensions for each row.

I solved this by creating a pointer variable and pointing it to the newly made level of the dictionary everytime i created a new level

```
def jsonify(data, dimensions, metrics, struc = {}):
    for row in data:
        pointer = struc
        for dimension in dimensions:
            pointer.setdefault(row[dimension], {})
            pointer = pointer[row[dimension]]
        for metric in metrics:
            pointer.setdefault(metric, 0)
            pointer[metric] += row[metric]
    return struc
```